# Removing ROI from image using JavaCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, colors, crop, javacv

I am learning JavaCV and want to extract part of images dynamically based on color.

As identification I am outlining the region which I need to extract with a color. Is there anyway I can do extract ROI based on color outline. Any help appreciated.

Here is the [Sample Image](http://s30.postimg.org/ahgoofn25/image.jpg)

Comment: just curious, why are you using javacv, not opencv's builtin java wrappers?

Comment: Well the implementation is what I am more concerned about. Doesn't matter if its javacv or opencv's java wappers.

Answer (score 0):

it is quite simple. Since your figure has 4 corners hence you ought to follow the following steps.

1.identify the orientation of the image and store the points in a MatofPoint2f in a specific order.
(clock wise or anti clockwise- For this you can use Math.atan2(p1(y)-centerpoint(y),p1(x)-centerpoint(x)) and then sort the points according to the result of the equation. find the center point by finding the avg all the xcoords and y coords or any method you prefer).

2.Create a MatofPoint2f containing the corner coords of the result image size you want the cropped image in.

3.use Imgproc.getPerspectiveTransform() to perform the cropping.

4.Finally use Imgproc.warpPerspective() to obtain the output that is desired.

And for creating the border of the ROI the best way to go is to threshold the image by using some specific range so as to extract only those parts of the spectrum which is required.

Comment: can you pls show some example code. I am just a beginner with opencv.

Comment: do you want the code to transform the image or for identifying the contour? Identifying the contour is some thing you have to figure out yourself.Try converting it into grey scale and identify the value of the pixel you want to select and change the rest of the pixels to black(0). the transform function is in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21571761/javacv-perspective-correction/23268237#23268237